# Rails 7 application.js syntax for importing libraries

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, import-maps

The [repository](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails) for rails importmaps provides an example for adding new libraries
`./bin/importmap pin react`
which then has to be imported in application.js
`import React from "react"`

This assumes a class definition of `React` which can intuitively be determined from the pinned library.  Confusion starts to emerge with
`import ReactDOM from "react-dom"`

What is that class? What is the convention?
Take `./bin/importmap pin javascript-autocomplete` ([resolves to this](https://ga.jspm.io/npm:javascript-autocomplete@1.0.5/auto-complete.js))
what is the class to be imported?
JavascriptAutocomplete
Javascriptautocomplete
javascript-autocomplete
autocomplete
Autocomplete
AutoComplete

The script uses `function autoComplete` `getAttribute("autocomplete")`
What is the import command handling in practice?